# Posting pictures on facebook with java selenium: element not interactable

Tags: java, facebook, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to post some text and pictures on facebook with a little Java program.

I am not able to send any image since I cannot click the appropriate button with selenium.

Here is the part of code where I need to click the upload Photo/video button on:

```
driver.navigate().to(group);
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='m9osqain a5q79mjw gy2v8mqq jm1wdb64 k4urcfbm qv66sw1b']//span[@class='a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7']")).click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']")).sendKeys(testoPost);
                
                for (File f : images) {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bp9cbjyn j83agx80 datstx6m taijpn5t l9j0dhe7 k4urcfbm']//i[@class='hu5pjgll bixrwtb6']")).sendKeys(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
```

Selenium navigates to one of the groups written in a text file and then opens the text/post window. Everything works fine until then I receive this exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

I don't know how to click the link to upload pictures, namely the Photo/video icon.

Anyone can help?

Thanks,
Saverio

[image: screenshoot]

Here is a screenshot of the html icon element I see when inspecting the upload button:

[image: Upload Photo button element]

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to interact with their website except using their API which means you may get banned? And you are aware that the class names that you hard coded may change any second which means your code will stop working even if you get it to work

Comment: Hi @WizKid, thanks for your reply. Yes, I am. I am just making an exercise to learn selenium web driver by posting a pic on a group of friends. However, I didn't know class name may change. I am not experienced with FE developement enough.